# suse cannot install software

Tags: networking, opensuse

I just installed suse 11.3, but cannot update the system. Update Applet says:

> PackageKit Error repo-not-available: Failed to download /media.1/media from http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.3/repo/oss/

I filled in my details in yast->proxy, and Firefox works fine with the same details. My laptop is a Packard Bell with ATI graphics card which I am yet to install. Could it be the network card?

Comment: On the command-line, what does `zypper lr`, `zypper -vv ref` and `zypper -vv up -D` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system time/date has reverted to January 1, 1970 or something ancient like that then your computers entire SSL infrastructure will temporarily be broken.

Connecting to software repositories usually is done over an SSL connection these days to prevent someone from doing a man-in-the-middle intercept attack.

Simply set your system date to be correct and downloading and updating software will magically resume working.

Comment: This same problem will affect Apple iPod Touch when battery completely loses its charge. Fortunately, the fix works on it too!

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same problem yesterday. Apparently, [download.opensuse.org](http://download.opensuse.org) has some stability issues.

Try again to another time, or switch to a [mirror](http://mirrors.opensuse.org/list/11.3.html). You can do this over YaST or on the command-line with `zypper`.

As an example, the following commands will disable the original oss repository, add a new one from a mirror and finally refresh it.

```
zypper mr -d repo-oss
zypper addrepo http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/opensuse/distribution/11.3/repo/oss/ mirror-repo-oss
zypper ref
```

And so forth for other repositories.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a valid network link? Can you reach other websites? Is there a firewall? Can you resolve hostnames, in particular that one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using yast software tool or zypper from the command-line.