# Yast is unable to access software repositories even though URLs are accessible in browser and system date is correct

Tags: opensuse, proxy, yast

I am using Yast on OpenSuse 12.1.  When trying to install packages from the software repositories, I get an error that the repo cannot be accessed because the network is unreachable:

> Download (curl) error for
>   'http://download.opensuse.org/update/12.1/repodata/repomd.xml': Error
>   code: Connection failed Error message: Failed to connect to
>   2001:67c:2178:8::13: Network is unreachable

I tried accessing this URL in the browser, and it works fine.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/suse-cannot-install-software) suggests that the system date may have reset itself, but that is not the case for me.  While it's a duplicate *question*, the accepted answer there is incorrect for me.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that Yast is trying to use IPv6, which probably you don't have. According to documentation for openSUSE 12.2 you can [turn IPv6 off in Network Settings](http://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.basicnet.html#fig.yast2.neticard) or manually:

> To enable or disable IPv6 manually, edit /etc/modprobe.d/50-ipv6.conf
>   and restart the system.

It's working in browser probably because when IPv6 fails it falls back to IPv4. In Firefox there are two options for IPv6 in about:config:

```
network.dns.disableIPv6;false
network.http.fast-fallback-to-IPv4;true
```

Comment: Disabling the entire IPv6 stack just because of one buggy program is not a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen a couple of times, due to network issues or time issues.

You mentioned you were able to get to the repo via web browser. Perhaps you were loading a cached version of the site.

Try the following, from a command line:

```
rcnetwork restart
zypper clean
zypper ref
```

You can go through YaST -> Network Devices -> Network Settings and disable IPv6 that way (it'll require a reset).

pbm's method works, but since you're already using YaST, I'm just showing how to do it through the GUI\TUI

Just for humor purposes, can you post the output of `date`?